# how to make Parameterization using Excel in selenium with junit (Read hidden excel data)

Tags: java, selenium, junit, parameter-passing

hi i am trying to get Data from external files read and loaded into the test script(multiple testcases) at runtime rather than hard-coding the same, or using @parameter annotation, I don't want to mention my parameters or my data in the script like in the below,

```java
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Class_Test {

    @Parameter(0)
    public String name;
    @Parameter(1)
    public String type;
    @Parameter(2)
    public String username;
    @Parameter(3)
    public String password;
    @Parameter(4)
    public String email;

    @Parameters(name = "{1}")
    public static String[][] data() throws IOException {
        return Reader.readDataFromExcel("Core_Test");
    }
}
```

Is there any way i can do that to hide my variable instead of exposing them in the test script

Comment: Do you want to hide them to prevent unwanted changes or to make them readonly or do you want source code readers not to be aware you are using Excel? The former is outright not possible, the latter... maybe

Comment: hi thx for your reply, i dont want to them be in main test script, it doesn't matter if code readers know if i am using excel or not, but not to directly know my passing parameters

Comment: What do you mean by "not ... know my passing parameters"?

Comment: sorry for the late respond, i mean test cases data to be read from excel sheet

Comment: i would like to read this part  from another class or something, not to be in my main test class, out of data privacy, but when i did that reading it from another class its giving me error message wrong number of argument                                                                       @Parameter(0)
    public String name;
    @Parameter(1)
    public String type;
    @Parameter(2)
    public String username;
    @Parameter(3)
    public String password;
    @Parameter(4)
    public String email;

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are generated by the method that is annotated with @Parameters. You may read from the Excel spreadsheet in this method.

```
@Parameters
public static Object[][] data() {
  //read the date here from the Excel file.
}
```

Comment: hi stefan thx for your respond, i have edited the code, i am already useing this annotation, but the thing is those passing parameters are the headers of my excel sheet and i would like to fetch them form another class or something, i dont want my data to be in the main test class.